# I want this program to return all the string values in a table form, but this is returning the value of last string only

Tags: arrays, c, string, substring, storing-data

Following are the conditions :

1. Take input of multiple strings from the user having same parameter.
   for Example :
   String 1 : Voltage 230,Current 3.14,PF 0.91,KW 1889.91
   String 2 : Voltage 240,Current 2.98,PF 0.84,KW 1889.92
2. Then split the string separated by commas and store the splited sub strings and then split again separated by spaces.
   for example : Voltage 230 (splited sub strings)
   Current 3.14
   PF 0.91

/* splitting the sub string from spaces */
Voltage   Current   PF      KW
230        3.14     0.91  1889.91
240        2.98     0.84  1889.92

3. Now we have the condition that if Voltage is  <230 && PF is < 0.85 do not log it.
   so the final output must be :

Voltage   Current   PF      KW
230        3.14     0.91  1889.91

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main() 
{
    char str[55];
    char *vol[5], *cur[5], *pf[5], *kw[5];
    int i, k = 0, m;
    char delim1[] = ",";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        printf("Enter value : ");
        gets(str);
        char *tk1 = strtok(str, delim1);
        while (tk1 != NULL) {
            if (tk1[0] == 'v') {
                vol[k] = strchr(tk1, ' ') + 1;
            } 
            else if (tk1[0] == 'c') {
                cur[k] = strchr(tk1, ' ') + 1;
            } 
            else if (tk1[0] == 'p') {
                pf[k] = strchr(tk1, ' ') + 1;
            }
            else if (tk1[0] == 'k') {
                kw[k] = strchr(tk1, ' ') + 1;
            }
            tk1 = strtok(NULL, delim1);
        }
        k++;
    }
    printf("Voltage \tCurrent \t PF\t\t\t kW\n");
    for (m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
        printf("%s\t\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n", vol[m], cur[m], pf[m], kw[m]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
Expected Output :

Enter value : Voltage 230,Current 7.89,PF 0.91,KW 1289.33   (1st user input)
Enter value : Voltage 230,Current 3.20,PF 0.84,KW 1100.32   (2nd user input)
Enter value : Voltage 240,Current 4.78,PF 0.91,KW 1278.87   (3rd user input)
Enter value : Voltage 230,Current 7.45,PF 0.91,KW 1945.34   (4th user input)
Enter value : Voltage 210,Current 5.13,PF 0.81,KW 998.33    (5th user input)

Voltage     Current      PF      kW
210     5.13        0.81        998.33      (latest string output i.e 5th string)
230     7.45        0.91        1945.34
240     4.78        0.91        1278.87
230     3.20        0.84        1100.32
230     7.89        0.91        1289.33     (oldest string output i.e 1st string)
Obtained Output :

Enter value : Voltage 230,Current 7.89,PF 0.91,KW 1289.33
Enter value : Voltage 230,Current 3.20,PF 0.84,KW 1289.32
Enter value : Voltage 240,Current 4.78,PF 0.91,KW 1278.87
Enter value : Voltage 230,Current 7.45,PF 0.91,KW 1945.34
Enter value : Voltage 210,Current 5.13,PF 0.81,KW 998.33
Voltage     Current      PF          kW
210         5.13        0.81        998.33
210         5.13        0.81        998.33
210         5.13        0.81        998.33
210         5.13        0.81        998.33
210         5.13        0.81        998.33
```

Comment: Stop using `gets()` immediately. It's a dangerous function because you can't specify the buffer size, and it has been removed from the language. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: All your pointers point into the same `str`, which you overwrite each time through the loop.

Comment: Thank you for adding the expected and obtained output.

Comment: we should use `fgets()` function instead of `gets()` .

Comment: Also to extract the values i tried this problem by using `sscanf()` function which will extract the string and numerical values and will also help in converting to other data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char input[100];
  int index = 0;
  float voltage, current, pf, KW;
  float readings[100][4];
  printf("INPUT FORMAT : Voltage 270.45,Current 70.89,PF 0.91,KW 128.33\n");
  printf("Enter string of readings:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(input, "Voltage %f, Current %f, PF %f,KW %f", &voltage, &current,
           &pf, &KW);
    if (pf > 0.75 && (voltage > 260 || voltage < 180) &&
        (current > 60 || current < 0)) {
      readings[index][0] = voltage;
      readings[index][1] = current;
      readings[index][2] = pf;
      readings[index][3] = KW;
      index++;
    } else {
      printf("Given values does not match the following condition\n1.PF> 0.75\n2.180 <Voltage< 260\n3. 0 <Current< 60");
    }
  }

  printf("Voltage\t\tCurrent\t\tPF\t\t\tKW\n");
  for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\n", readings[i][0], readings[i][1],
           readings[i][2], readings[i][3]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
**Expected and Obtained Output :**

INPUT FORMAT : Voltage 270.45,Current 70.89,PF 0.91,KW 128.33
Enter string of readings:
Voltage 270.45,Current 70.89,PF 0.91,KW 128.33      // first input
Voltage 170.45,Current 70.89,PF 0.81,KW 128.33      // second input
Voltage 270.45,Current 55.89,PF 0.91,KW 128.33   /* third input with 
                                                     wrong current                                                    
                                                        value*/
Given values does not match the following condition  
1.PF> 0.75                              /* Error because of current*/                                                      
2.180 <Voltage< 260
3.Current>60

Voltage 270.45,Current 70.89,PF 0.71,KW 128.33    /*fourth input with 
                                                    wrong PF value*/
Given values does not match the following condition 
1.PF> 0.75                                    /* Error because of PF*/
2.180 <Voltage< 260
3.Current>60

Voltage 290.45,Current 75.89,PF 0.91,KW 128.33      //fifth input


Voltage     Current     PF      KW
290.45      75.89       0.91    128.33  //output of 5th input(Recent)
170.45      70.89       0.81    128.33  //output of second input 
270.45      70.89       0.91    128.33  //output of first input(oldest)

NOTE : Output for 3rd and 4th didn't log because of error.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).